# Apexchart and percent data labels

Tags: apexcharts

I am looking into using Apexcharts and would like to know if there is an option to have the data labels generated outside the slices with lines pointing to the associated slice?  I have cases where the slice is small and prevents the application from generating the slice percent.  This is a sample of what I am currently generating:

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 slices that do not show a percentage, I assume because the area of slice is to small to generate the percentage.  If the percentages could be rendered outside the slice with a line or arrow pointing to its associated slice, that would be great.  Is that option available?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the percentage values outside the slices, if yes then you do this:

```
  dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  style: {
      offsetX: -6,
      colors: ['#333'],
      fontSize: '11px',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
},
```

[Read more](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/)